# How query only a subpath in mongoose without precising any value?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I would query only a part of my document but without precising any value to retrieve, just to avoid to query the whole document. I have seen the different queries, even the `where` query, but seems all require a value to match with the document's properties,

for example:

here my Model.Schema:

```
const ScheduleSchema=new Schema({
    month:{type: Number, required:true},
    day:{type: Number, required:true},
    hour:{
        morning: {
            time: [{
                timePlot:String,
                prospect:[{ 
                    type: documentType,
                    ref:"Prospect"
                }]
            }]      
        },
        afternoon:{
            time: [{
                timePlot:String,
                prospect:[{ 
                    type: documentType,
                    ref:"Prospect"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

How would only fetch the afternoon section for example, however, the queries I have seen so far ask to me to provide some value to match with my path, so my question is how query for a subpath providing only the path instead of `path:value`. For example as following

```
Model.find({path: afternoon}, () => {...}
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying which parts of the document to return is done by providing a projection argument to [`find`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) as the second parameter:

```
Model.find({path: afternoon}, 'path', () => {...}
```